# Default current location pin in Skobbler map

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using skobbler map for Android. I do not require current location to pointed on the map, so I am not registering for the current location listener and skobbler map itself adds an default current location pin on the map. Please check the image attached. [image: screenshot] , please tell me how to not display this. And, by default the maps takes to Berlin, Germany can this be avoided? If yes, how?

Comment: Is this a picture from the emulator or the real device?

Comment: Picture is from a real device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the behavior of the default position annotation with `mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(false)`.
To center the map on a desired location use `mapView.centerMapOnPosition(skPosition)`.
Where `mapView` is your `SKMapSurfaceView` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code hope its help you.As its working at my end.

```
@Override
    public void onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition skPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = skPosition;
        SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(this.currentPosition);
        mapView.animateToLocation(skPosition.getCoordinate(), 7);
        mapView.animateToZoomLevel(7);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call in onSurfaceCreated:

```
SKCoordinate coord = new SKCoordinate(-37.585162f, 40.418143f); 
mapView.setPositionAsCurrent(coord, 0, true); 
mapView.setZoom(4);
```